# Add index on alias column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to sort the query result on an alias column (total_reports) which is in group by condition with limit of having 50 number of records.
Please let me know where I am missing,

```
SELECT Count(world_name) AS total_reports, 
       name, 
       Max(last_update)  AS report 
FROM   `world` 
WHERE  ( `id` = '' 
         AND `status` = 1 ) 
       AND `time` >= '2017-07-16' 
       AND `name` LIKE '%%' 
GROUP  BY `name` 
HAVING `total_reports` >= 2 
ORDER  BY `total_reports` DESC 
LIMIT  50 offset 0
```

Query return what I need. However it runs on all records of table then return result and takes too many time which is not right way. I have thousands of records so its take time. I want to apply key index on alias which is total_reports in my situation.

Comment: What is `name` LIKE '%%' supposed to do?

Comment: You cannot apply an index to total_reports. You should add the world table definition (show create table world) and an explain plan to the question.

Comment: `id = ''`? Isn't the `id` the table's primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index on an column from an aggregated result? No, I'm sorry, but MySQL cannot do that natively.

What you need is probably a **Materialized View** that you could index. Not supported in MySQL (yet), unless you install extra plugins. See [How to Create a Materialized View in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86790/best-way-to-create-a-materialized-view-in-mysql).

**The Long Answer**

You cannot create an index on a column resulting from a `GROUP BY` statement. That column **does not exist** on the table, and **cannot be derived at the row level** (not a virtual column).

You query may be slow since it's probably reading the whole table. To only read the specific range of rows, add the index:

```
create index ix1 on `world` (`status`, `id`, `time`);
```

That should make the query use the filtering condition in a much better way and hopefully will speed up your query, by using and *Index Range Scan*.

Also, please change `'%%'` for `'%'`. Double `%` doesn't make too much sense. Actually, you should remove this condition altogether -- it's not filtering anything.

Finally, if the query is still slow, please post the execution plan, using:

```
explain <my_query_here>
```